# Will forward-declaration of two classes lead to circular dependency in the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

Is this allowed? I am trying to determine if there is a risk of circular dependency in the constructor.

Header file:

```
class B; //forward declaration 

class A
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<B> cObj;
    std::vector<B*> cList;
    A();
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A& aObj) : aObjLocal(aObj) {};
    void ShareData(int result);
private:
    A& aObjLocal;
};
```

Cpp file:

```
void B::ShareData(int result)
{
    for (auto& iterator : aObjLocal.cList)
    {
        (*iterator).ShareData(result);
    }
}

A::A()
{
    cObj = std::make_unique<B>(*this); // <- Will this cause circular dependecy 
}
```

Thanks in advance for sharing the knowledge.

Comment: Thing about circular dependencies is that you can simply test whether it compiles. If it compiled then there is no circular dependency. So, does your program compile?

Comment: It's complicated. Yes its compiling. However, this code is not yet been consumed anywhere yet. It will be consumed only in the future.

Comment: `cObj = std::make_unique<B>(*this);` should not compile as `cObj` is a `B *` and there is no implicit conversion from a unique pointer to a regular pointer.

Comment: @Phil970 , I meant to make B a smart pointer. I have corrected the code. Thanks for pointing it out. Can you please clarify if there is a case of circular dependency here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no circular dependency appearing here, since `B` does not contain an actual object of type `A` but only a reference. That way, `*A::cObj` has a well-defined size upon construction and does not depend on the implementation details of `A` (if `B` contained an actual `A` instead of a reference, a circular dependency would occur, the memory required to create an `A` would be infinite).

Lets have a look at a small example (I made `aObjLocal` public just to be able to print the address):

```
int main(){                                                                                          
 A a;                                                                                               
 std::cout << "Address of a:                   " << &a << std::endl;                                                                      
 std::cout << "Address of aObjLocal of a.cObj: " << &((*(a.cObj)).aObjLocal) << std::endl;                                                
}
```

The output will look something like this

```
Address of a:                   0x7ffe68b95f70
Address of aObjLocal of a.cObj: 0x7ffe68b95f70
```

So `a.cObj` does contain the correct reference to `a`, the code works as intended (assuming this behavior is the intended one).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the explanation.